# What's the correct way to deal with multithreading and Realm?

Tags: android, multithreading, realm

On my Android application I have a data access layer where  I have the following property on each data store class

```
Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
```

My problema is when I try to call any data store method from a different thread. Then I get

> Realm objects can only be accessed on the thread they were created.

I've read that I should be creating a new Realm instance on the new thread. Problem is that data access layer is no thread aware, it doesn't know if it's called from main or separated and it seems to me it would smell adding logic to check that.

I was checking different questions here and issues filled on github but it's not clear for me what's the oficial way to handle a situation like this. I don't think I'm dealing with a strange scenario...

**EDIT**

My arquitecture is Fragment containing a Presenter whic contains a DataStore.

I detected a very long running process so I moved it to a separated thread like this on presenter

```
Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // Events is a collection of DTOs, they are not Realm objects (converted from Realm object to DTO inside dataStore)
        events = dataStore.getEvents(filterTerm);

        view.getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if (events.size() > 0) {
                    view.showEvents(events);
                }
            }
        });
    }
});

thread.start();
```

**EDIT**

Adding 3 queries executed in a row. They are called from 3 different methods

**Query 1**

```
final RealmResults<Event> results = query.findAllAsync();
results.addChangeListener(new RealmChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onChange() {
        ....
    }
});
```

**Query 2**

```
final RealmResults<T> result = realm.where(type).findAllAsync();
result.addChangeListener(new RealmChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onChange() {
        ...
    }
});
```

**Query 3**

```
final RealmResults<PresentationSpeaker> results = query.findAllAsync();
results.addChangeListener(new RealmChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onChange() {
        ...
    }
});
```

Comment: Can you comment a bit more on your architecture and what libraries you use. Without that your question is really broad. Also in what scenarios are you switching threads?

Comment: @ChristianMelchior: not sure what you mean with which libraries I use, I use a lot, but none is relevant for this problem except Realm. Please let me know if I miss something

Answer (score 3):

It is normally custom to let your DataStore be asynchronous to avoid exactly the problems you run into now: That the operation are taking to long, and you have to create custom threads and use `postRunnable`. This should be something the DataStore is concerned about, not your Presenter and UI which should run on the UI thread. One solution is to let your Datastore be asynchronous instead, either by implementing some observer pattern yourself or use RxJava. Then you could use Realms async API's (https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#asynchronous-queries) to do the following:

```
// DataStore
public class DataStore {

   private final Realm realm;

   public DataStore() {
     realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance(); // Called on the UI thread
   }

    public void getEvents(EventsLoadedListener listener) {
      RealmResults<Event> results = realm.where(Events.class).findAllAsync();
      results.addChangeListener(new RealmChangeListener() {
        public void onChange() {
          if (listener != null) {
            listener.eventsLoaded(results);
          }
        }
      });
    }

    public interface EventsLoadedListener {
      public void eventsLoaded(List<Event> events);
    }

}

// UI code
datastore.getEvents(new DataStore.EventsLoadedListener() {
    public void eventsLoaded(List<Event> events) {
      view.showEvents(events);
    }
})
```

The above code can be massively simplified using RxJava, so I would really encourage you to look into that. Realm also supports RxJava natively: https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#rxjava

Comment: I'm afraid something is off about this solution. I removed my thread creation logic and now I have 3 async queris in a row. In random basis `onChange` listener is not called on `RealmChangeListener`. I'm sure I'm attaching listener correctly since some times it hit it (it seems to depends on how heavy is the query performed). I'm sure it's not returning since shouldn't take very long.

Comment: Added code to attach listener on those queries. Some times `onChange` runs, sometimes it does't. For the same query parameters it always behave the same: it runs or it doesn't. I'm 100% sure that in all cases it reaches `findAllAsync` line

Comment: When it behaves wrong, only firt query returns and the other 2 never reach `onChange`

Comment: The posted code looks correct, but doesn't say much about the context it is called in.

Comment: I really appreciate your help but it's not easy to paste 1500 lines of code here, I'm trying to paste relevant code but if you want to see anything in just let me know :)There is no interesting logic on how I call methods containing those queries, just a line after the other in the main thread, without anything fancy. I've seen similar problems reported on github, maybe I just have to upgrade from 0.84 to latest versión. Thanks!